# Custom lexer Error Message in JavaCC

Tags: java, javacc

I want to customize the lexer error message, I have my exception class that subclasses TokenMgrError and redefined the function but how do I ensure that in Lexer2TokenManager class, that it will do

```
throw new mysubclassexception(.........)
```

instead of

```
throw new TokenMgrError(.......)
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example

Comment: Did you try subclassing the lexer and overriding LexicalError as described in the documentation at https://javacc.java.net/doc/apiroutines.html ?

Comment: I followed that and subclasses TokenMgrError and redefined the function LexicalError. But how do I get it to throw my exception now?

Comment: Good question.  I'm looking into it.  Meanwhile you could just rewrite the code of `LexicalError` in `TokenMgrError`.  Your rewritten code will not be overwritten by JavaCC, though you might want to make a copy somewhere else, just in case.  You will see a message `Warning: TokenMgrError.java: File is obsolete.  Please rename or delete this file so that a new one can be generated for you.` You can safely ignore this message until the next time you upgrade JavaCC, at which time you should delete all generated files and re-rewrite `LexicalError`.

Answer (score 0):

Could the documentation that the comments refer to be out of date?

Whenever I want to use a custom exception class I insert a try / catch block in my production rules.  Something along the lines of this;

```
(
  ...
  { 
    try {
      ...
    } catch (Exception e) {
      ...
      throw new MyCustomException ( e, customMessage );
    }
  }
)
```

Perhaps not the most elegant solution but it has always been adequate for me. Hope it helps.